# Can I Convert X509 Certificate to string/byte to use later?

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have a situation where I need X509 certificate and have easy way to pass strings to it. Can I somehow convert the certificate to string and back to certificate?

I tried the following and everything works good except the certificate thumbprint is changed.

```
var originalCert = new X509Certificate2("C:\\cert.pfx", "password");
var byteCert = originalCert.GetRawCertData();
var stringCert = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byteCert);
var convertedBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(stringCert);
var convertedCert = new X509Certificate2(convertedBytes);

var equalThumbprints = originalCert.Thumbprint == convertedCert.Thumbprint; //this returns false
```

How can I get exact same certificate in this case?

shouldn't the certificate thumbprint be unique and be generated by certificate authority?

Comment: seems to me that pfx is a binary format, hence not suited to be encoded/decoded to unicode characters. If you have invalid unicode characters, you will "lose" them. Try to encode the byted as Base64 instead, for instance? Base64 is exactly done to represent arbitrary bytes as string with a limited set of characters, suited for exchange in text formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments, when you need to transfer byte array over text transport and to retain its integrity, you should use Base64 encoding:

```
String b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(originalCert.RawData);
```

and then when you need to restore byte array from string:

```
Byte[] rawData = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);
```

Base64 uses only ASCII table (in fact, only 7 bits) and is resistant to control characters, such as CR/LF/CRLF, spaces, tabs and other characters.

Comment: ToBase64String, not Tobase64String

Answer (score 1):

To answer the doubt on thumbprint here is the answer:

> The thumbprint is dynamically generated using the SHA1 algorithm and
>   does not physically exist in the certificate. Since the thumbprint is
>   a unique value for the certificate, it is commonly used to find a
>   particular certificate in a certificate store.

More [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.thumbprint?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2_Thumbprint) ...

To check whether you have the same certificate then use the [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.equals?view=netcore-3.1#:~:text=Remarks,same%20issuer%20and%20serial%20number.&text=The%20Equals%20method%20should%20not,property%2C%20or%20the%20Thumbprint%20property.) method.

```
 var equalcerts = originalCert.Equals(convertedCert);
```

***UPDATE***

> The Equals method should not be used when comparing certificates for
>   security purposes. Instead, use a hash of the RawData property, or the
>   Thumbprint property.

So create your new certificate with RawData something like:

```
    var originalCert = new X509Certificate2("C:\\cert.pfx", "password");
    var byteCert = Convert.ToBase64String(originalCert.RawData);            
    var convertedCert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(byteCert));            
    var equalThumbprints = originalCert.Thumbprint == convertedCert.Thumbprint; //true
    var equalcerts = originalCert.Equals(convertedCert); //true
```

Comment: When I use FromBase64String I get the correct result. Maybe the thumbprint bytes lost integrity during Unicode conversion as suggested by @Crypt32. Looks like integrity of thumbprint is not checked when I create it from byte array. If I had a test case to validate that certificates are equal using the Equals method, I would still have bug in my code. Here is what happens when I use Unicode in stead of Base64

**var equalThumbprints = originalCert.Thumbprint == convertedCert.Thumbprint;** //this is false
**var equalCert = originalCert.Equals(convertedCert);** //this is true

Comment: Plz dont use equals. I teste this with base 64 and the thumbprint was true!